# ORDER BY optimization

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I have a query:

```
SELECT t3.a1, t2.a2, t2.a3
     , sqrt(pow(x1-x2, 2) + pow(y1-y2, 2)) AS distance
     , t1.* 
 FROM t1
 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.t1_id = t1.id
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT (t1_id is not null) as a4, t1_id, a5
              FROM t4
             WHERE a6 = '1234' 
               AND a7 = true) AS t3 
    ON t3.t1_id = t1.id
 WHERE t1.a8 IS NULL 
   AND a9 = 'asdf' 
   AND a10 = 'qwer'
   AND a11 >= 1 
   AND a11 <= 4 
   AND a12 <= 10 
   AND a12 >= 6
   AND x1 != 0 
   AND y1 != 0 
   AND x1 IS NOT NULL 
   AND y1 IS NOT NULL 
   AND t1.id NOT IN (SELECT t_id 
                       FROM t4
                      WHERE t1_id = '1234')
 HAVING (distance <= t1.a1 AND distance <= 50) 
    OR (t1.a15 = true) 
    OR t1.a16 = true 
 ORDER BY t1.a17 DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

Of course the `EXPLAIN` for this is a little rough:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: t1
         type: ref
possible_keys: a11,a12,a8,a10,a9,x1,y1
          key: a8
      key_len: 6
          ref: const
         rows: 18601 (this is a test db, for prod this is much higher)
        Extra: Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: t2
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 8
          ref: id
         rows: 1
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: <derived2>
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 2
        Extra: Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: 3
  select_type: SUBQUERY
        table: t4
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,t1_id
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 8
          ref: const
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where; Using index
*************************** 5. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: DERIVED
        table: t4
         type: ref
possible_keys: a6,a7
          key: a6
      key_len: 8
          ref: const
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index condition; Using where
```

This query takes close to a second. I think the biggest issue for performance is the `Using filesort` in the first one, which I gather is because of the `ORDER BY`. So I distilled the query down to something very small to try to get the index to work with the `order by`, ignoring other potential issues with other parts of the query.

I see that according to the [mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/order-by-optimization.html) something very basic such as: `explain select * from t1 order by a1` should work assuming there's an index on `a1`, but that's not what I'm seeing:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: t1
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 37202
        Extra: Using filesort
```

I can get the index to work if I explain `select id from t1 order by a1`.

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: t1
         type: index
possible_keys: NULL
          key: a1
      key_len: 9
          ref: NULL
         rows: 37202
        Extra: Using index
```

I've also tried getting the indexes to work with my range conditions (`a11 >= 1 AND a11 <= 4`), but that doesn't seem to work either.

What options do I have for optimizing a query like this? I've considered using a materialized view for the t1/t2 join, but that won't fix the sorting issue. I've also considering using a spatial index to speed up the distance query.

For the record I have modified the column and table information. I think they shouldn't matter, but I can provide more specifics if they're necessary.

I have to use `HAVING` to compare the calculated value `distance` to values in my table. As for the question about `a15` and `a16`, those are parameters that make the distance irrelevant, so I'm combining the logic as (`distance < <some value> or <distance doesn't matter>`).

There's really two parts to my question, the second is why doesn't using an index for the order by clause work unless I mangle it significantly, regardless of data type. I can tell you the type of `a1` in the example (`double`), or the type of the primary key (`id`, `integer`), or the type of `a9` (`varchar`). No matter the case, it doesn't work.

Comment: So on doing more research, it appears that the issue here is that I was missing some context in clustered/covering indexes vs. nonclustered indexes. According to my understanding of it, having an index on the a17 alone wouldn't cover all of the data in my table, so it can't be used for the order by cleanly. So I can try to optimize other things, but I'll probably always have to do the filesort the way things stand.

Comment: You are trying to solve something that can't be solved -- you can't use one index for selecting rows and a different one for sorting, because using any one index for one purpose precludes using any other index in the same table for any other, which is a limitation of any RDBMS.  In the specific query above, a *single* index on (a8,a17) (in that order) could potentially be used for both simultaneously, possibly eliminating the filesort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alas, `EXPLAIN` does a poor job at pointing out the real villain.  I have made it a career to know how to optimize MySQL queries.  Here are some of the basics that I have managed to make somewhat digestible:

[MySQL: Building the best INDEX for a given SELECT](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

The following are very likely to be performance killers; see if you can rewrite the query to avoid them:

- `LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ... )`
- `OR` -- `UNION` is sometimes an alternative
- `NOT IN ( SELECT ... )` -- Consider `LEFT JOIN .. IS NULL` or `NOT EXISTS`.

Barring that, the best index (that I can see for what you have) is

```
INDEX(a9, a10, a17)
```

Answer (score 0):

Such complex conditions used by `WHERE`, especially those having greater/lesser comparisons, can not be efficiently indexed and will be VERY slow. Even worst case is when some kind of functional condition is used for `WHERE` or `JOIN...ON`

I suppose that this is the case of bad database design that can't be speeded up at all. Even if some progress will be made with this particular query, every next query's performance become worst.

Structural and functional decomposition should be revised